# Vue — detect when "final" updated() event happens

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there an easy way to detect when a component has finished updating?

I have data loading into a component from the store and from API calls and, as you might expect, the updated() {} is going to fire a bunch of times until the dust settles.

How do I know when the component has updated() for the last time? I realize a component can't possibly know if it's never going to update again, but how does one wait for the initial updates to finish without a timeout?

Comment: How do you define what the "last update" is - translate that into code

Comment: @JaromandaX that's exactly my quandary. I think it would come down to figuring out all the events / children that are causing my component to update and then watching the sum of those activities. I was wishing there was an afterUpdated() method, but I know that doesn't make sense. :\

Comment: A hacky way would be to use a debounced function that only executes after not being called again within X ms.